# Mobile navigation javascript issue

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've spend a better part of a day trying to get a mobile menu to work on my Wordpress site. The hamburger menu appears fine, but unlike another site I used this menu on, this one doesn't work. I'm fairly certain that its javascript issue, but I'm not getting any console errors or any errors in the VS Code.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<section class="header-nav">
            <div class="container borders">
                <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
                    <!-- <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="topics-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Topics Menu', 'mystic' ); ?></button> -->
                    <?php
                    wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'theme_location' => 'menu-2',
                            'menu_id'        => 'topics-menu',
                        )
                    );
                    ?>
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation --> 
            </div>      

            <nav id="mobile-navigation" class="main-navigation">
                    <!--<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="topics-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Topics Menu', 'mystic' ); ?></button>-->
                    <?php
                    wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'theme_location' => 'menu-2',
                            'menu_id'        => 'topics-menu',
                        )
                    );
                    ?>                  
                    
        </nav>
<!-- #site-navigation -->
        </section>
```

Javascript:

```
        class Header {
    constructor(){
        this.burger = document.querySelector('.burger')
        this.nav = document.querySelector('#mobile-navigation')

        this.events()

    }

    events(){
        this.burger.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
            this.toggleBurger(e)
        })

        window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
            this.handleWindowResize()
        })
    }

    toggleBurger(e){ 
        jQuery(this.nav).slideToggle();
        jQuery(this.burger).toggleClass('open');
    }

    handleWindowResize(){
        if(window.innerWidth > 768){
            jQuery(this.nav).slideUp()
            jQuery(this.burger).removeClass('open');
        } else {
            // jQuery(this.nav).slideUp()
            // jQuery(this.burger).removeClass('open');
        }
    }

 
}


export default Header
```

Comment: please provide a full html not the php stuff and describe what exacly is not working

Comment: const button = siteNavigation.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[ 0 ];

// Return early if the button don't exist.
if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
    return;
}

Comment: You are using return inside a function, so if the button is undefined the function returns  without doing anything

Comment: I changed the code on my site and edited my question. Thanks.